# SQL query to find where ID does not exist in another column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table: **Accounts**

```
+-----------+-----------------+------+
| AccountNo | ParentAccountNo | name |
+-----------+-----------------+------+
|         1 | null            | ABC  |
|         2 | 1               | ABCD |
|         3 | 1               | CDE  |
|         4 | 2               | DEF  |
|         5 | null            | GHI  |
|         6 | 3               | MNO  |
|         7 | 5               | JKL  |
+-----------+-----------------+------+
```

I need to get results where `AccountNo` does not exist in `ParentAccountNo`.

For example, based on the data above, the results I expect are:

```
+-----------+-----------------+------+
| AccountNo | ParentAccountNo | name |
+-----------+-----------------+------+
|         4 |               2 | DEF  |
|         6 |               3 | MNO  |
|         7 |               5 | JKL  |
+-----------+-----------------+------+
```

Will accept answer for `MySQL` or `SQL-Server`.

Comment: How did you get 4, 6 and 7? Parent id 2, 3 and 5 exists in the table.

Comment: I have edit the question. the result will : 4,6,7

Comment: Which is it `mysql` or `sql-server`?

Comment: I need to see differrent of both of them. So Both its okay. But prefer SQL SERVER

Comment: @anonyXmous 4,6,7 do not have any child in parentAccountNo table. 4,6,7 do not have any value in parentAccountNo

Comment: @Brien AccountNo = 7 with ParentAccountNo = 5 it is mean that 7 is a parent of AccountNo = 5 and don't have any child

Comment: @Brien anonyXmous what is not detail in here  ? I can explain

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By joining the table to itself with a `LEFT JOIN` on the `AccountNo` = `ParentAccountNo`, you can then filter out the rows where there were no matching `ID`'s.

```
WITH Accounts AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (1,null,'ABC'),
                 (2,1,'ABCD'),
                 (3,1,'CDE'),
                 (4,2,'DEF'),
                 (5,null,'GHI'),
                 (6,3,'MNO'),
                 (7,5,'JKL')) V(AccountNo,ParentAccountNo,name))


SELECT t1.* 
FROM Accounts t1
LEFT JOIN Accounts t2 ON t1.AccountNo = t2.ParentAccountNo
WHERE t2.AccountNo IS NULL
```

[image]

[[DEMO HERE]](http://rextester.com/AYHSZ78795)

---

You were curious about the usage of [**`WITH`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql). . .

Here is an equivalent to my shorthand usage of [**`WITH`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql):

```
CREATE TABLE Accounts (
    AccountNo INT NOT NULL,
    ParentAccountNo INT NULL,
    Name VARCHAR(200))

INSERT INTO Accounts
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (1,null,'ABC'),
                 (2,1,'ABCD'),
                 (3,1,'CDE'),
                 (4,2,'DEF'),
                 (5,null,'GHI'),
                 (6,3,'MNO'),
                 (7,5,'JKL')) V(AccountNo,ParentAccountNo,name)
```

Comment: Its just a quick way for me to create sample data instead of `CREATE TABLE. . .` then doing an `INSERT INTO. . .`

Comment: Yes this is i mean. But i don't undesrtand why i got -1 downvote :(

Comment: Well. I think people didn't understand your question. I will take some time to edit it for you so it is more clear.

Comment: Thank You Brien. It help me solve the problem at work now :) . I don't even think to filter the same table with join to got the row.

Comment: @DennisLiu I have also updated my answer to include extra info about the usage of [**`WITH`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql)

Comment: @Brien, If you don't mind, I would like to ask one thing in your join query. Is there any problem? if I check null ParentAccountNo of second table. Like the following query

SELECT t1.* 
FROM Accounts t1
LEFT JOIN Accounts t2 ON t1.AccountNo = t2.ParentAccountNo
WHERE t2.ParentAccountNo IS NULL

Comment: In where condition you have checked t2.AccountNo IS NULL. But If I check t2.ParentAccountNo IS NULL. Is there any problem to come desired value? Thanks.

Comment: @Emdad - No change in result. You can check for `null` on `t2.ParentAccountNo` as well. Please see my [DEMO HERE](http://rextester.com/AYHSZ78795) link and try it. You could also check for `t2.Name IS NULL` with the same result.

Comment: Thanks for your nice cooperation.